# Google Map (jQuery script) does not fill page height on mobile viewport

Tags: jquery, css, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on Django project w/ Bootstrap 3. The goal is to display a Google Map at full page width and height, beneath the nav bar. I'm able to do so on standard desktop viewports. On mobile screen widths, however, a grey area appears at the top and bottom of the map.

Desktop: http://screencast.com/t/3r0vBviNrK

Mobile: http://screencast.com/t/37YM8ifFdpw

I've set the parent div to 100% and tried using absolute positioning.

**html + jQuery**

```
<div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    jQuery(function($) {
        // Asynchronously Load the map API 
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });

    function initialize() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        // Multiple Markers   
        var markers = {{ marker_list|safe }};

        // Info Window Content
        var infoWindowContent = [

        {% for instance in queryset %}
            ['<div class="info_marker_content">' +
            '<a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ instance.thumb }}" height="80" width="80"></a>' +
            '<h3><a class="location-font-map" href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ instance.location }}</a></h3>' +
            '<p><a class="qnote-font" href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ instance.quick_note }}</a></p>' +        '</div>'],
        {% endfor %}
        ];

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Allow each marker to have an info window    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }       
    }

</script>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#map_wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute !important;
}

#map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Make it easier. If the map is only you want show set `#map_canvas` to `position: fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;`

That should do it.

**Update**.
To keep your bar on top, set top property to the height of your menu bar. Example: `top: 20px;`

Comment: Still getting the same issue on mobile. Are you suggesting to keep map wrapper as I have it in the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all width values with 100vw and all height values with 100vh.

(In place of 100%).

100vw = 100% of the viewport width
100 vh = 100% of theviewport height.

Comment: Will work in all iOS devices cause of an issue: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1805

Comment: Interesting, never heard of that. Didn't solve the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery Mobile, header and footer are the two standard types of toolbars which can be positioned in different ways as discussed in [Toolbar positioning options](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/docs-bars.html).

For immersive interfaces like map viewer which requires to fill the entire screen with the the map itself, you can use Fullscreen fixed toolbars. To enable this option on a fixed header or footer, add the data-fullscreen attribute to the element.

Full screen fixed header markup example:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```

Full screen fixed footer markup example:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
    <h1>Fixed Footer!</h1>
</div>
```